# Retrieving value from SQL TYPE to resultSet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, resultset

I'm querying a table in oracle sql using TYPE keyword i'm differencing the results.the query is below

```
SELECT row_id,
  distribution_id,
  product_id,
  'CARD' TYPE
FROM product_distribution
WHERE status = 'Pending'
AND date_out < SYSDATE
UNION ALL
SELECT row_id,
  distribution_id,
  product_id,
  'CASH' TYPE
FROM prod_cash_distribution
WHERE status = 'Pending'
AND date_out < SYSDATE
```

while Retrieving with Result Set i'm getting the type null. But i need to get card or cash based on which query executed? Thanks in advance

Here is java Code

```
String sql=" SELECT row_id,distribution_id,product_id,'CARD' TYPE
    FROM product_distribution
    WHERE status = 'Pending'
    AND date_out < SYSDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT row_id,distribution_id,product_id,'CASH' TYPE
    FROM prod_cash_distribution
    WHERE status = 'Pending'
    AND date_out < SYSDATE";
PreparedStatement prest = prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next()){
                    prodDto.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    prodDto.setDistributionID(rs.getInt(2));
                    prodDto.setprodId(rs.getString(3));
                    prodDto.setType(rs.getString(4)); //here i'm getting null
                  }
```

Comment: As I understand, you retrieve the data using java. Can you show your java code?

Comment: Do you get values for the first three parameters?

Comment: Yes..i'm getting first three parameters..only type alone not getting

Comment: Just to be sure: does rs.getString(4) return null or it returns value but the type field of prodDto is set to null?

Comment: Yes..it's working now..actually the update session not committed..so changes didn't took effect..after commit and run the code works fine...thank you Guneli..

Comment: Happy it was resolved. You are welcome!